# Bernoulli distribution mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, means

I understand that the expected value of a Bernoulli variable is $p\cdot1 + (1-p)\cdot0 = p$, since it provides the amount of outcomes that match a condition out of the total possibilities, on a single try.

But why is the mean of the distribution $p$ as well? Shouldn't it be a weighted average of the values of the outcomes (for example, 3.5 on a dice toss)? Or are there any definitions that I'm confusing?

Comment: Expected value of a random variable and mean of its distribution are the same thing. As for your dice example, the results of a dice roll just aren't Bernoulli distributed (unless it's a d2).

Comment: (And even if it is a d2, it would need to be a d2 labeled 0 and 1, rather than, say, 1 and 2.)

Comment: Ok. So Bernoulli is just a matter of taking a value as given and calculating the chances that it can be true or false, and not of calculating the possible values it can take on a single try, as I was taking it?

Comment: The possible values a Bernoulli random variable can take *are* $0$ and $1$.